# Replace first instance object in python

Tags: python, class, object, import, multiple-instances

I have a course project (it is completed, no I am not asking for anyone to do work for me) it is requiring me to reverse an instance of an object (firstObj01(str) -> secondobj02(str)). I tried using the instance into a tuple, dictionary, different loops, etc. I figured out a write/read method that would do this for already known values (write to file first instance replace with second instance). The first code is a code I am unable to alter in any way.

```
    #DO NOT MODIFY THE CODE IN THIS FILE
#File: Proj03.py

from Proj03Runner import Runner
import turtle
import random

window = turtle.Screen()
turtle.setup(300,300)

rand = random.randrange(0,2) #get a random number
#set object's colors based on the random number

if(rand%2==0):
    #rand is even
    color01 = "red"
    color02 = "green"

else:
    #rand is odd
    color01 = "green"
    color02 = "red"

objA = Runner(color01) #create one object
objB = Runner(color02) #create a second object

#Call the run method on each object and unpack
# the tuple that is returned.
colorA,turtleA,yourName = objA.run()
colorB,turtleB,yourName = objB.run()

window.title(yourName)

#Manipulate the turtles to draw a picture.
turtleA.color(colorA)
turtleA.forward(50)
turtleA.circle(50)

turtleB.color(colorB)
turtleB.right(180)
turtleB.forward(50)
turtleB.circle(50)

tempTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
tempTurtle.shape("turtle")
tempTurtle.left(90)
tempTurtle.color(color01)
tempTurtle.stamp()

#Pause and wait for the user to dismiss the window.
window.mainloop()
```

and the code that I worked out is:

```
import turtle
import os
if os.path.exists("floresK909112.txt"):
    os.remove("floresK909112.txt")
    print ("operation performed")

class Runner:   
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
        self.name = "Flores"

    def turt():
        a = turtle.Turtle("turtle")
        a.pensize(3)
        a.color()
        return a

    def appendB(self):
        b = open("floresK909112.txt", "a")
        b.write(self.color + '\n')
        b.close()

    def readB(self, a):
        b = open("floresK909112.txt", "r")
        line = b.readline()
        count = (len(line))
        if count >5:
            self.color = "red"
            b.close()
            return (self.color, a, self.name)
        else:
            self.color = "green"
            b.close()
            return (self.color, a, self.name)

    def run(self):
        a = Runner.turt()
        b = Runner.appendB(self)
        c = Runner.readB(self, a)

        return c
```

Again, I am not looking for anyone to do my homework. Is there a way to do this with; shadowing, all loops but while loop, a dictionary, or any other (basic) process? The end product is two circles same color and the turtle stamp being the first color. The profs code is requiring two tuples to be unpacked and majority of the processes I used had issues with returning to few arguments. (3 arguments required 2 given) while using lists converted to strings and passed in a tuple it did not return enough arguments. Same with a 2d tuple. I attempted to search different forms of shadowing and other methods I mentioned but could not reference them to this scenario.   I would be more than happy to seek tutoring at college... however, I'm currently not in country and have no other means. Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: What is reverse instance ?

Comment: Is a reverse instance an instance that performs some turtle movement in reverse order?

Comment: No, the intial instance is objA being called by the initial program that is importing my program requiring a specific color (colorA). The turtles are moved with there individual colors (TurtleA yields ColorA+ movement, TurtleB...) I need ColorB (which is passed with the second instance) to be the color returned for BOTH  objA and objB. So, I need objB to be objA and objB. If they were both objA's color than the stamp doesn't work correctly and creates another issue.

Comment: Otherwise, it is just unpacking a Tuple which isn't really creating an instance... it is just receiving the instances information (if I am understanding this correct).

Comment: I felt I was pretty clear... I apologize, It is not a "reverse instance". I said "requiring me to reverse an instance of an object (firstObj01(str) -> secondobj02(str)). Implying  the second object needs to come first. So, is there a way to accept two pieces of information (color01, color02) pass them both in. alter it so it only accepts and sends out color02.